# Travelling straight forward, but not in a straightforward way

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, geography

[image]

I started with Romania on my north side, and Hungary to my east, and from those borders I kept travelling as far southwest as I could, never turning.

Which country did I end up in?

---

Hint 1 (after the first full day):

> [@jafe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41973/jafe) might be able to buy a ticket that helps on this journey; most other PSErs would probably find hailing a taxi more useful.

Hint 2:

> There's a small hint in the comment section, and a huge hint right above it.

Hint 3 was in the bounty text, which is preserved as a screen shot above.

Comment: Possible spoiler that I can't ROT-13 so I'm pastebinning instead: https://pastebin.pl/view/b82ec2bc . But I doubt it's relevant, to be honest.

Comment: Your instinct serves you well, that would indeed be way too straightforward. :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So I admit to not being positive about this, but I think the answer might be:

> The Seychelles

Reasoning:

> There are several clues to look at flags. Hint #2 mentions that there is a huge hint above the comments...one of the options there is "flag". Also, the bounty mentions "flying colors". And from @Stiv, the bounty also uses the phrase "mark my puzzle for special attention". And from @jafe (in Finland) and explanation of Hint #1: the Finnish word for "ticket" is the same as for "flag", while others may need to "flag a taxi". So look at the flag of the Seychelles:
>
>  [image: Flag of the Seychelles]
>
>  Across the top ("north") face are the colors of the Romanian flag:
>
>  [image: Flag of Romania]
>
>  Down the right ("east") side are the colors of the Hungarian flag:
>
>  [image: Flag of Hungary]
>
>  If you follow all these colors to the bottom left corner ("southwest") you get the flag of the Seychelles.

Comment: This is a really nice spot +1 It's also doubly frustrating that I didn't spot this as I had a puzzle in the pipeline which relies in part on this exact scenario! Ah well, one to rewrite and use another time :)

Comment: Also, "mark my puzzle for special attention" is another pointer towards the hint you spotted...

Comment: Thanks @Stiv! Good catch on the latter...I'll edit it in.

Comment: Nice work! Hint 1: rot13(Va Svaavfu gur jbeq "gvpxrg" vf gur fnzr nf "synt"... Sbe bguref, "synt n gnkv")

Comment: @jafe Thanks! I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: Just so. The bounty is coming your way once the system decides it has forced us to wait long enough.